# Resizing Delphi form after resizing its font in form editor

Tags: forms, delphi, resize

I develop a legacy Delphi 6 application, and I would like to increase the font size of one of the forms. All other forms have `Microsoft Sans Serif 8pt`, but this one is set to `Microsoft Sans Serif 7pt`. All controls have `ParentFont = True`, so I could simply set the font size of the form to `8pt`. The problem is that the form and its controls won't resize, and the text of the labels would overlap. Is there a simple way to resize the form after resizing its font, without resizing its controls manually in the form editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At designtime you can effect the change by editing the .dfm file manually. Make sure that the form is saved with the `Scaled` property set to `True`.

Then, close your project in Delphi, or close Delphi altogether. Next open the .dfm file in a text editor and adjust the forms `TextHeight` property. For example, if you want to scale from 7pt to 8pt, and `TextHeight` is set to `13`, then you should change it to `11`. Then re-load the project and open the form in the designer and your form will be scaled. This won't be a perfect scaling because you aren't allowed floating point values for `TextHeight`. But it may be good enough.

---

At runtime, you can to call [`ChangeScale`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.ChangeScale):

```
ChangeScale(NewFont.Size, OldFont.Size);
```

Note that `ChangeScale` is a protected member. So, depending on where you are calling this, you may need to use the protected member hack.

One option then would be to call the form persistence framework at runtime to generate a scaled version of the .dfm file. That would allow you more precise control than playing tricks with `TextHeight`

For example, you can attach the following to the `OnShow` event of your form:

```
procedure TMyForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  BinaryStream, TextStream: TStream;
begin
  BinaryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Try
    BinaryStream.WriteComponent(Self);
    BinaryStream.Position := 0;
    TextStream := TFileStream.Create('MyForm.dfm', fmCreate);
    Try
      ObjectBinaryToText(BinaryStream, TextStream);
    Finally
      TextStream.Free;
    End;
  Finally
    BinaryStream.Free;
  End;
end;
```

This will generate a new .dfm file based on the runtime state. You can then compare this with the version of the .dfm file that is in your revision control system. There will be a few changes that you won't want to accept, but mostly the changes will be the position and size changes that you do want.

Comment: Thank you, David, but I would like to resize the form "in development time", and not "in runtime".

Comment: @kol Personally my feeling is that the runtime option with `ChangeScale` is still the best. This will give you the most accurate scaling.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the first method, and it worked perfectly. Interestingly, I cannot find anything in Help about the TextHeight property of TForm. Would you please tell me how it works?

Comment: @kol I don't really know. I was expecting `PixelsPerInch` to be the one. I think these are magic properties that store the metrics for the machine that last designed the form. If you open the form on a machine with different font scaling then `ChangeScale` will be called and the form will be scaled. But I don't remember the details. It's ages since I last looked.

Comment: @kol You can create an expert which will call ChangeScale at design time.

Comment: @Torbins That would be a very slick approach. Whether it's justified for a one-time process is debatable. I'd personally have expected to see this functionality in CnPack/GExperts but I could not find it on their websites.